Hilton/Stammbach Exercise 4.7.3
I'm having trouble with one of the exercises in Hilton & Stammbach's A Course in Homological Algebra. The problem is below:
Let $M^{*} = Hom_{\Lambda}(M,\Lambda)$ for any $\Lambda$-module $M$. Let $P_{1}\rightarrow P_{0}\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ be an exact sequence of $\Lambda$-modules with $P_{0}$, $P_{1}$ finitely generated projective. Let $D = coker(P_{0}^{*}\rightarrow P_{1}^{*})$.
Show that the sequence $0\rightarrow Ext^{1}_{\Lambda}(D,\Lambda)\rightarrow M\rightarrow M^{**}\rightarrow Ext^{2}_{\Lambda}(D,\Lambda)\rightarrow 0$ is exact.
The hint is to consider the diagram with the top row $P_{1}\rightarrow P_{0}\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ and the bottom row $0\rightarrow K^{*}\rightarrow P_{0}^{**}\rightarrow M^{**}$, where $K = ker(P_{1}^{*}\rightarrow D) = coker(M^{*}\rightarrow P_{0}^{*})$. (Sorry I do not know how to draw it here)
I'm able to show the hinted diagram commutes and that $P_{0}\rightarrow P_{0}^{**}$ is an isomorphism. I believe we might need to use the snake lemma to show the given sequence is exact, but I can't see how after trying for quite a while.
